# Spring+Hibernate Do I have to create a model to store and fetch data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

In my Spring MVC project, I have a three tables Question, Tag, and Question_Tag. Models for Question and Tag already exists but there is no model for Question_Tag table. Question_Tag table basically stores the question_id and associated tag_id (ManytoMany just like StackOverflow). Now, to add a tag to a question, store the data in the table, to retrieve question count of a tag and other things do I need to create a question_tag model or it can be done without the model. 
I am implementing it not using createQuery but will be using criteria builder. Also, I have to use the joins on the Question_Tag class in the criteria query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need a model for that.  I have a project that uses @ManyToMany and there is a table automatically generated and updated etc by hibernate.

You know you don't need a model because it is just the ids.

Comment: And I should put this @ManyToMany in which class Question or Tag?